# Turn a Matlab figure in 'axis square'

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Suppose I have received a figure from my colleague, i.e I wouldn't build the figure by myself, and I not necessarily know hot to plot it.

I want to turn the figure's axis into 'axis square' or 'axis equal'.
I am familiar with the axis style command, only when imposing it on my figure from the command line, and not in the situation mentioned.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the figure and issue the `axis equal` command:

```
f = open('myfigure.fig');
axis equal
```

You can then save the figure in the normal way to a new file.  Commands like `axis equal` always operate on the "current figure", which is usually the figure most recently plotted to, or selected.

Comment: *Commands like axis equal always operate on the "current figure"* This is only true if you don't specify the axes on which to operate explicitly: `axis(hax, 'equal')` which is always the best way.